# The Go client and 'etcdctl' cli utility tool seem to be working on different workspaces even though they are connected to the same hosts

Tags: go, etcd

I wrote a little Go program that connects to etcd hosts `http://192.168.0.210:2379` and `http://192.168.0.211:2379`, sets a key `/foo` to `bar` and then reads it and prints the result. That part is working fine:

```
bar &{get {Key: /foo, CreatedIndex: 6, ModifiedIndex: 6, TTL: 0} <nil> 6 67b31bc85ffd6d2b} <nil>
```

the key can also be read using a HTTP GET request

```
{
    "action": "get",
    "node": {
        "key": "/foo",
        "value": "bar",
        "modifiedIndex": 6,
        "createdIndex": 6
    }
}
```

but when I use ectdctl it returns nothing as if the key didn't exist

```
./etcdctl --endpoints=192.168.0.210:2379,192.168.0.211:2379 get /foo
```

if I instead set `/foo` using etcdctl, then it works and reads the key correctly. It looks like etcdctl is working on a workspace of its own. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Could be the values are set using version 3 of etcd api. Run `export ETCDCTL_API=3` before you run etcdctl, as noted at https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/dev-guide/interacting_v3.html

Comment: I always ran etcdctl with api v3

Comment: Apparently the Go client uses API v2. Running etcdctl with api v2 works. @nos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was using API v2 for the client and v3 for the etcdctl. Different API versions have different key namespaces. To use client v3 in Go import `go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3`